# why does this one event handler work but the other one fails?

Tags: react-native

Can you explain the technical difference between the 2 following implementations and why one breaks and the other one works?  Here's the target function:

```
  loginWithEmail(){
     this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginWithEmail');
  }
```

The following onPress implementation will successfully call the loginWithEmail() function, but the following error is thrown within the loginWithEmail() function:

"this.props.navigation is undefined"

```
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.loginWithEmail}>
                <Text>
                    Log in with Email
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
```

However, if I wire up the onPress event handler function with an arrow function format like the following example, the loginWithEmail() function executes successfully without error:

```
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.loginWithEmail()}>
                <Text>
                    Log in with Email
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
```

Can you explain the technical difference between the 2 following implementations and why one breaks and the other one works?   Does this have something to do with "closures"?

Comment: `this.loginWithEmail` is a reference to a function, `this.loginWithEmail()` calls a function (difference in parentheses). That's different. I might be able to expand on it if that doesn't help enough?

Comment: In the first example, the keyword `this` (within `this.props`) is referencing something different than in the second example.

Comment: The react documentation has a very clear explanation of binding class methods and different approaches in the section on ES6 classes: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html